# patching random.choice in each run for a test case

Tags: python, unit-testing, random

I have a function that loops over a certain number of times and picks a random element from a list each time.

The problem is while writing testcase for this.

Sample code

```
def func(given):
    combo = [filled by a function]
    for i in range(0,given):
        com = random.choice(combo)
```

and my test case is like

```
@patch('random.choice',2)
def test_func():
    func(250)
    assert(expected,actual)
```

so when the test case runs , I want to dynamically give different value in each run for random.choice.

how can this be achieved ?

Comment: The meaning of the question is unclear? What does it mean to "be different in each run"? If you ask for a random number, it may come out the same number twice in a row.
If we avoid this, we will lose the randomness

Comment: you want this --> https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html which means switching to `pytest`

Comment: @BaruchG. What I mean is , when func is called 250 times , I want to inject the value from the test case to random.choice in each of the 250 calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `mock`, you can use the `side_effect` parameter of `patch`.

If you pass an iterable, each time a call is made to the patched object, this will return the next value in the iterable. Because an example is always clearer, here's a simple one:

```py
import mock
import random

def my_function_to_test():
    value = random.randint(0, 10)
    print("Value: %d" % value)
    return value

@mock.patch('random.randint', side_effect=[1, 2, 3])
def test(mocked_random):
    value1 = my_function_to_test()
    print('My value is 1: %s' % (value1 == 1))

    value2 = my_function_to_test()
    print('My value is 2: %s' % (value2 == 2))

    value3 = my_function_to_test()
    print('My value is 3: %s' % (value3 == 3))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

You should get:

```
Value: 1
My value is 1: True
Value: 2
My value is 2: True
Value: 3
My value is 3: True
```

That's not a real test like one from `unittest`, or any equivalent testing framework, but the idea is here.

Please note that you should be careful of the use the patched object as most times as there's values in the iterable that `mock.patch` uses, otherwise you'll get a `StopIteration` exception raised. In the example above it would mean that I cannot use my patched `random.randint` more than 3 times.

Hope this helps!